# Leer contenido html obtenido con curl

Tags: php, html, curl

Leer el contenido html de un curl, el problema es que yo obtengo los datos los cuales resultan 200200200, el problema es que cada "200" significa algo y si hay un error puede variar a 408 pero al intentar hacer la comparación

```
    if($respuesta == 200 && $respuesta2 == 200 && $respuesta3 == 200) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Completed without errors";
        echo "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Completed with errors";
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

da siempre Completed without errors aunque la página devuelva 200408200 por ejemplo.
Decir que hago 3 curls iguales pero con diferentes POST.

```
    $ch3 = curl_init('http://api.afafa.us/minecraftbridge.php');
    curl_setopt ($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'apikey=private&command=unban '.$nick.' -s&server=1');
    curl_setopt($ch3,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
    $respuesta3 = curl_exec ($ch3);
    curl_close($ch3);
```

Saludos

Comment: Los códigos 200 y 408, ¿te refieres a los códigos de respuesta HTTP? ó ¿son valores en el cuerpo de la respuesta?.

Comment: Son valores en el cuerpo de la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentacion la funcion [`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php) retorna `true` o `false` no 200 ni 408 como indicas, segun el codigo que compartiste.

En cambio la función [`curl_getinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-getinfo.php) si puedes obtener lo que requieres.

Tendrías que almacenar la respuesta del status  de esta forma

```
$ch3 = curl_init('http://api.afafa.us/minecraftbridge.php');
curl_setopt ($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'apikey=private&command=unban '.$nick.' -s&server=1');
curl_setopt($ch3,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
$respuesta3 = curl_exec ($ch3);
$status3 = curl_getinfo($ch3, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch3);
```

Y luego hacer la comprobacion

```
if($status1 == 200 && $status2 == 200 && $status3 == 200) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Completed without errors";
        echo "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Completed with errors";
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER indica si esperamos recibir algún contenido como respuesta. False indica que no. Si en lugar de false se setea a true, entonces curl_exec devuelve ese resultado (o false si hubo un error).

Comment: Ya, lo que pasa es que no son códigos http si no que los números se devuelven en texto plano.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` debería ser `true`, de lo contrario te regresará un booleano, el cual en caso de éxito, en la *comparación flexible* `==` será verdadero: `true == 200` = `true`, por lo que también deberías usar una *comparación estricta* `===`.

Otra opción es dejar `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` en `false` y hacer la comparación estricta: `$respuesta3 === TRUE`.